# How many samples do I need to estimate the click-through rate confidently?

Tags: probability, statistics

In online advertisement,

```
Click-Through-Rate = Clicks / Impressions
```

How many clicks or impressions do I need that I can confidently say our tomorrow's CTR is almost what I compute for historical data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use the [confidence interval](http://www.seomanchester.com/blog/conversion-rate-confidence-479/) for click through rate` to achieve my goal.